# For the following layout, for example zoom's room, what kind of Qt component widgets will use?

Tags: qt

I am trying to use Qt5 to design an interface like the following zoom's room.

Basically, what kind of widgets will be suggested to design such kind of layout.

[image: zoom rooms layout example]

Answer (score 0):

For such a design I would suggest not to use Qt Widget, but instead use Qt Quick.

You can do the whole interface by using `Image`, `Text`, `Rectangle` and `MouseArea` plus some graphical effects for the shadows. You might be able to leverage some already made controls from `Qt Quick Controls 2` like `Button` or `Label`.

Comment: Thanks. Since I am the newbie with Qt, not even for qt quick. So how about if I stick to the old way? Are QLabel, pushbutton widgets enough for this layout?

Comment: @kevinatso If you are a newbie to Qt, go with Qt Quick. Widgets will not be easier to use especially if you need to do this kind of interface. QGraphicsScene isn't a good solution for me, if you're new to Qt and you must lean you'd better learn the best way to do it which is Qt Quick

Answer (score 0):

The issue with using widgets for this is that they'll look like widgets. I think you'll end up spending more time than it's worth to style them to look like the flat interface in your example. If you don't want to use Qt Quick--which I don't use, but know enough that it's targeted for this kind of interface--then I'd suggest looking into QGraphicsScene and QGraphicsView. In a QGraphicsScene, you create graphic elements, and you make them respond to mouse clicks, position them exactly, make them partially transparent, and so on. Qt has a set of built-in classes that derived from QGraphicsItem; those are probably sufficient to do a lot of what you're looking to do.